# Unable to login using jmeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have recorded login script using jmeter and when I run it the user is not logged in. There is no session parameter to pass.

Below is application which used for my study.

```
www.gandermountain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the network dump

[image: gandermountaincookies]

I believe all you need to do in order to mimic the login is just to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting while running your script? If you are not able to logon, add the cookie manager (Test Plan -> Add -> Config Element -> HTTP Cookie Manager) under your test plan.

If it doesnt work, check any other parameter values getting changed in your home page and login requests. If yes, parameterize that too and then try. It will work